# Getting error while executing PowerShell cmdlet on ubuntu machine

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, permissions, scripts

I was currently running PowerShell on ubuntu machine with the help of VS code by importing packages. The commands which I used are:

```
sudo apt update;
sudo apt-get install libunwind8;
wget https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.0.0-alpha.9/powershell_6.0.0-alpha.9-1ubuntu1.14.04.1_amd64.deb;
sudo dpkg -i powershell_6.0.0-alpha.9-1ubuntu1.14.04.1_amd64.deb;
PowerShell;
```

The question was:
1Q) Write PowerShell program to print following names as slash (/) separated values using the write-host cmdlet.

- mark
- john
- grace
- bob

A) The cmdlet which I wrote was **write-host ("mark", "john", "Grace", "Bob") -separator "/"**

I wasn't worried about the cmdlet. However, I was worried about the error that was generated while executing the command. It was in the form of Linux script.

```
user@workspacew4qquyie4n761nqx:/projects/challenges if [[ -f /home/user/.local/share/powershell/PSReadLine/ConsoleHost_history.txt && $(grep -io -e "Mark" -e "John" -e "Grace" -e "Bob" /home/user/.local/share/powershell/PSReadLine/ConsoleHost_history.txt | wc -l) -gt 4 ]]; then echo "SCORE:100%";else echo "SCORE: 0%"; fi
```

I was new to the shell scripting and it would be helpful for me if someone explains this error.

Regards,
Surya Kumar.

Comment: Can you add the error in your question?

Comment: Please provide OS & release details; Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is long past it's EOL & ESM support is off-topic here.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard or public support*) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL (*end-of-life*) thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 14.04 ESM is in *extended* support and supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage thus also off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Comment: Did you run a program inside of PS and *then* type your cmdlet? The output you are seeing looks like it might be from some kind of response-checking or grading code.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these commands and observe the resulting output.

```
$ sudo snap install powershell --classic
powershell 7.2.3 from Microsoft PowerShell* installed
$ snap run powershell
PowerShell 7.2.3
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.

PS /home/karel> write-host ("mark", "john", "Grace", "Bob") -separator "/"
mark/john/Grace/Bob
```

As you can see the cmdlet executed correctly without any error.